# Is $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is cyclic since it is generated by $\pm1$, e.g. $n=n\cdot1$ for an $n\in\Bbb Z$.

I think that $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is not cyclic cause it is not finite group.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cyclic groups don't have to be finite

Comment: What is your definition of cyclic?  Does it explicitly require that a group be finite?

Comment: my teacher said that every cyclic group should be finite and generated by one element.

Comment: The standard definition of "cyclic group" is "[generated by one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group)." (In fact, that's the *only* definition I've ever heard, but I could imagine some texts adding a finiteness hypothesis.) So yes, $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic according to the standard definition.

Comment: is the finiteness important Or not? that is my problem.

Comment: Can you ask your teacher for clarification -- "Can a cyclic group be infinite?". Either you've gotten a mistaken impression of what they said, or your teacher is using "cyclic group" differently than most people do. Because, like @NoahSchweber. I've never heard of finiteness being a requirement for being cyclic.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC  I will ask him.

Comment: In fact, any infinite cyclic group is canonically isomorphic to  $(\mathbb{Z},+).$

Comment: @Bumblebee Give me an isomorphic from a cyclic group $G$ to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: A cyclic group is canonically isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$

Comment: A monogenous group is canonically isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$

Comment: @MAROUANEARJDAL: If you look at carefully, I mentioned "infinity". However, I should admit that,  here the word canonical is bit ambiguous as the isomorphism is unique up an inverse. For example take the generator of your group and map it to $1$ (or you can also map it to $-1.$)

Answer (score 2):

A group $(G,*)$ is said to be **cyclic**, if it is generated by one group element. Concretely this means there exists some $g\in G$ such that for every element h there is a natural number $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $h=g^{*n} = g * ... * g$ ($\vert n \vert$ times). Here $g^{*(-k)} = (g^{-1})^{*k}$.

$(\mathbb Z, +)$ **is** cyclic, as (somewhat tautologically) every element $n$ can be written as $n=1^{+n}$. Up to group isomorphism it is the only infinite cyclic group though.

Indeed, if $G$ is another cyclic group generated by some element $g$ the assignment
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb Z & \rightarrow & G\\
1^{+n} & \mapsto & g^{*n}
\end{array}$$
yields an isomorphism of groups (it is surjective as $G$ is cyclic, injective as $G$ is infinite and clearly a homomorphism).

Comment: is the finiteness important Or not?

Comment: You were faster than I could edit. Not really. $\mathbb Z$ is the only infinite cyclic group.

Comment: @MAROUANEARJDAL No, finiteness is not part of the standard definition. It's conceivable that you're using a text which defines it differently (although I'd be extremely surprised); otherwise, either you misheard or your teacher made a mistake.

Comment: I learn from my class that $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is not cyclic cause it is an infinite group. A cyclic group should be finite. if you do not agree why $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is the only cyclic infinite group.

Comment: As others pointed out in the comments it is nonstandard to make finiteness a part of the definition of cyclic groups. If your teacher did, ask him why. I added some more details, as requested.

Comment: $(\mathbb{Z},+) $ is a monogene group.

Comment: Okay. I never heard that word before, but if he likes to make a distinction there, why not. Imo he should have mentioned that he uses nonstandard terminology though...

Comment: can you show me the proof of Z isomorphic to G (with G is cyclic group)?

Comment: I already added the details. What is specifically unclear to you?